# jenkins pipeline code flow after if else

Tags: jenkins, logic, jenkins-pipeline

Hi I'm trying declare few variables based on the if condition.

example :

```
if(params["MYPARAM"]=="some_value"){ 
def var="sample"
}
else {
"do nothing/quit JOB"
}
echo "${var}"
```

This echo at the last line doesn't have the value even the condition is satisfied.

How to get the values in next block after the success condition with declaration statement.

Thank you for your valuable answers.

Comment: Try define `def var` before the if block. I think if you define it inside the if block it is out of scope for the `echo` part.

Comment: Yes you're correct. any other alternatives to make variable declaration(with multiple conditions)  in scope for whole program ?

Comment: Define `def var` outside of your function. Then it should be in a global scope.